# Apps Scrip : function IsUnderline()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a custom function for Google Sheet called to count the number of underlines cells in a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `getCell(j, i)` and `getFontLine()` are used in a loop, I'm worried that the process cost becomes a bit high. When the process cost is reduced, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS(prange) {
  return SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(prange)
    .getTextStyles()
    .reduce((n, r) => {
      r.forEach(c => {
        if (c.isUnderline()) {
          n++;
        }
      });
      return n;
    }, 0);
}
```

- In this case, it supposes that `prange` is a string value of A1Notation. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getTextStyles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#gettextstyles)
- [isUnderline()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#isunderline)

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you have a solution with A1Notation instead of string value ?

Comment: @M. D. Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `Do you have a solution with A1Notation instead of string value ?`? I would like to think of a solution by correctly understanding it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your support. I meant a solution where in a cell I would write =COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS(K7:AO7) instead of =COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS("K7:AO7")

Comment: @M. D. Thank you for replying. When `getTextStyles()` is used, the range is required to be used. In this case, when the custom function is used with `=COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS(K7:AO7)`, `K7:AO7` is the cell value. So, in this case, `=COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS("K7:AO7")` might be simpler. But, if you are required to use `=COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS(K7:AO7)`, please modify `.getRange(prange)` to `.getRange(Array.isArray(prange) ? SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula().match(/\((.+)\)/)[1] : prange)`. By this, both `K7:AO7` and `"K7:AO7"` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
function COUNT_UNDERLINED_CELLS(prange) {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(prange);
  const numRows = range.getNumRows();
  const numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var count = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= numRows; j++) {
      if (range.getCell(j, i).getFontLine() == "underline") {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).